# show dateTime dataType in DataContract model on swagger UI via swashbuckle webapi 2 C#

Tags: datetime, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I am using a datacontract for the model and the datetime datamember is working properly, however swagger ui is showing the datatype as string instead of dateTime.

datamember example:

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Order = 6), XmlElement(Namespace = apiNameSpace, Order = 6)]
public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; } = null;
```

swashbuckle swagger-ui model output:

StartDate (string, optional):

Answer (score 2):

This is per the Swagger 2.0 spec (see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md).

The spec says that a dateTime should be represented as a string type, with the associated "format" property set to "date-time".

Have a look at http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/store/placeOrder if you want to see an example. "shipDate" there is defined as (string, optional) just like your StartDate field.